# latitude longitude from craigslist

Tags: geolocation, yui, yql

Using YQL and apartment search location from craigslist, I get a result in the following form. Is there any way I can get latitude,longitude information from this ? or do i have to geocode the address ? are there any other source apart from craigslist that can be used to get property details along with geo-location?

```
{
      "about": "http://kolkata.craigslist.co.in/apa/2559284148.html",
      "title": [
       "Temporary Stay Rental (Kasba Area, Kolkata) 2bd 1100sqft",
       "Temporary Stay Rental (Kasba Area, Kolkata) 2bd 1100sqft"
      ],
      "link": "http://kolkata.craigslist.co.in/apa/2559284148.html",
      "description": "FURNISHED apartment for executives, professionals, NRIs and visitors for temporary stay in Kolkata (Calcutta).<br>\n<br>\nLOCATION: Kasba area near Delhi Public School - close to Gariahat and EM Bypass<br>\n<br>\n2 bedrooms, 2 bathrooms, a spacious living room, a separate dining room and a modular kitchen. Cooking facility - cooking gas burner, utensils, refrigerator etc. <br>\n<br>\nApartment located at the second floor of a four story building.  Elevator available.<br>\n<br>\nHot water, air conditioned bedrooms and one covered parking space available.<br>\n<br>\nRent is INR 2,000.00 (or USD 50.00) per day for a minimum stay of 15 days. Costs of electricity and cooking gas charged separately on actual usage.<br>\n<br>\nShorter stay possible at negotiable rates.<br>\n<br>\nAppropriate ID required for renting.<!-- START CLTAGS -->\n\n\n<br><br><ul class=\"blurbs\">\n<li> <!-- CLTAG GeographicArea=Kasba Area, Kolkata -->Location: Kasba Area, Kolkata\n<li>it's NOT ok to contact this poster with services or other commercial interests</ul>\n<!-- END CLTAGS -->",
      "date": "2011-08-22T10:05:43+05:30",
      "language": "en-us",
      "rights": "Copyright &copy; 2011 craigslist, inc.",
      "source": "http://kolkata.craigslist.co.in/apa/2559284148.html",
      "type": "text",
      "issued": "2011-08-22T10:05:43+05:30"
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to map the regionId's to the coordinates or zipcode.